# Rotating a transparent png image over a background image with android API=8

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I have two images.  The background is this
[image] and the other is this [image]
The second one has a transparent background.  Both are PNG images.  I have a layout with the arrow over the background and it looks perfect, like this [image]

I want to rotate the arrow to point in the direction the wind blows. I have a loop that runs once a second and updates the angle each loop.

here is my layout:

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameMasthead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonReturn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" >

        <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageMasthead"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:src="@raw/masthead"
        />
        <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageMastheadFly"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:src="@raw/masthead_fly"
        />
```

And here is the code I have tried after searching both Google and SO.

```
imageMastheadFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMastheadFly);
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageMastheadFly.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) awa, imageMastheadFly.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageMastheadFly.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
imageMastheadFly.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

it compiles and runs but the results are not what I want.  Every so often I notice that the pointer is passing by outside of the frame and full size, not the reduced size of the frame. Here is an example of what I see:

[image] You can see that the background is fine but the arror is full size and off outside the frame.

Some of the answers I found do not work because this is a API=8 application so that it will run on all of my phones.

If I give up on the api=8 requirement and change the code to this:

```
imageMastheadFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMastheadFly);
imageMastheadFly.setRotation((float) awa);
```

It works fine.  It just will not work with older phones like my Nexus-One

I also had to add this to the XML

```
android:rotation="0"
```

---

Answer #1 suggested I follow a tutorial, which I did.  Here is the code I ran:

```
imageMastheadFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMastheadFly);
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
Bitmap bMap;
bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
matrix.postRotate((float) awa);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0,
bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
imageMastheadFly.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

What happened was that the image of the arrow was not used but instead my application's ICON was on top of the background.  When it rotated, it did not just rotate but it scaled itself so that it would fit in the framelayout even when rotated 45 degrees.  This is not what I want.  I want the arrow to rotate without scaling so it looks like the wind is just rotating the arrow.  This code, from the tutorial, looks wrong. It looks like the specification of what image is rotated is missing and sure enough it didn't work correctly.

I was able to get RotateAnimation to work in API=8 so the problem is solved.  Here is the code.

```
imageMastheadFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMastheadFly);
RotateAnimation r; // = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO);
r = new RotateAnimation((float)oldAwa, (float)awa, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
r.setDuration((long) 1000);
r.setRepeatCount(0);
imageMastheadFly.startAnimation(r);
oldAwa = awa;
```

Comment: I changed the API level to 11 and changed the code to this:     imageMastheadFly = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMastheadFly);
    imageMastheadFly.setRotation((float) awa); and it works perfectly. If nobody here has an answer, I will just give up on the old phone.  I will add this to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ImageView's matrix to rotate it, your problem was probably caused by setting the rotation origin wrong - probably something to do with using the bounds of drawable rather than the size of the view.

Don't create a bitmap each time.

Alternatively, you can use a RotateAnimation on the View where fillEnabled, fillAfter, fillBefore are all set to true.

Comment: I tried this line instead of the drawable call: matrix.postRotate((float) awa, imageMastheadFly.getMeasuredWidth()/2, imageMastheadFly.getMeasuredHeight()/2); and it acts about the same.  The arrow is full size, not scaled to the frame and rotates outside of the frame.

Comment: RotateAmination worked.  Thank you.  I will post the code in the question

Comment: I set the rotation to go from its old value to its new value in the 1 second update rate of my code.  Looks very nice as it smoothly moves from one value to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the Decoding the image to Bitmap. Check out the tutorial [here](http://droid-examplecode.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-image-rotation_01.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: That was pretty strange.  I copied the code over and modified to match my image name.  I wondered why the tutorial didn't seem to use the name of the image in the rotation code.  When I ran it, the image was not the one I wanted but instead my icon.  It did rotate but changed size as it did it.  It scaled so that the entire image would still fit in the frame.  I want the image to stay the same size so it looks like the pointer is just rotating.  I think I will just give up and use API=11 unless I get a more detailed answer that works.

Comment: It did work in API=8.  I will post what I did and see if anyone can find out what I need to change.